# Select a query within a query that leads to opposite result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having issues trying to display the correct column from my select within select query

```
SELECT
      merchant.merchantname  'MerchantName'
    , COALESCE(COUNT(transaction.transactionid),0) 'NoofTransaction'
    , COALESCE(SUM(transaction.transactionamount),0) 'TotalAmount'
    , (         SELECT
                  statement.statementbalance
            FROM statement
            WHERE transaction.transactionid = statement.transactionid
            ORDER BY
                  statementbalance DESC LIMIT 1 
      )                      
      AS 'BalanceRemaining'
FROM merchant
LEFT JOIN transaction ON merchant.merchantid = transaction.merchantid
AND transaction.transactiondate = '2018-01-16'
GROUP BY
      merchant.merchantid
ORDER BY
      merchant.merchantid ASC;
```

This is the statementbalance queueing down from sorted by the transactionid. On my BalanceRemaining column for the date `'2018-01-16'`I should be getting 7. Instead, I kept getting 500 from all the merchants listed when the sql query specifically order by descending order and limit the row returned to 1. Same thing will happen if i change it to get from transactionid

```
    statementbalance
    ===
    500
    .
    .
    233
    90
    7
```

Sample data for tables: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ec29f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not ordering by the correct column. If you want a value for the latest date then you need to order by a DATE and TIME columns in descending order:

```
SELECT m.merchantname as MerchantName,
         COALESCE(COUNT(t.transactionid), 0) as NoofTransaction, 
       COALESCE(SUM(t.transactionamount), 0) as TotalAmount,
       (SELECT s.statementbalance
        FROM statement s
        WHERE m.merchantid = s.merchantid
        AND s.statementdate <= '2018-01-16'
        ORDER BY s.statementdate DESC, s.statementtime DESC
        LIMIT 1 
       ) as BalanceRemaining
FROM merchant m 
LEFT JOIN transaction t ON m.merchantid = t.merchantid
                       AND t.transactiondate = '2018-01-16'
GROUP BY m.merchantid
ORDER BY m.merchantid ASC;
```

To enable this also change the way the data is correlated, NOT by transactionid, but by merchantid instead.

```
| MerchantName | NoofTransaction | TotalAmount | BalanceRemaining |
|--------------|-----------------|-------------|------------------|
|         Dog1 |               0 |           0 |           (null) |
|         Cat2 |              13 |         115 |            24.16 |
|      Parrot3 |               1 |          20 |           299.25 |
|      Beaver4 |               0 |           0 |           (null) |
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc2440/3

Comment: The date column that i have is static e.g, '2018-01-16' throughout the day with time separated in another column. the only plausible way to sort descending is thru the transactionid and statementid. In this case, the highest/latest transactionid of that particular date to fit the "Balance Remaining" column. But i tried and it still give me the result in reverse irregardless of the ORDER. I also tried your way of putting the DATE column which in this case is `statement.statementdate` or 'transaction.transactiondate'. Still reverse result

Comment: without sample data it is extremely difficult to be helpful as each "answer" or "comment" is based on a guess of some sort. **Perhaps** the join in that correlation should be at merchant level and not transaction level? then sorting by the date and time column (or combining those columns) would work. Do consider providing sample data or setup a sqlfiddle

Comment: added some data, notice Cat2 is getting 124.41 where it should be getting 24.16

Comment: and the url is what? it changes when you alter the DDL

Comment: thanks for the response, but it's not grabbing the correct balance remaining when i shift to another date with different balance remaining. it will keep getting the latest balance ignoring the date

Comment: Here's the new sqlfiddle link with more sample data on different dates:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5428d8/1

Comment: what is the "expected result"?

Comment: the date is actually substituted as a variable for a php script. It changes everyday depending on CRON. The expected result is to reflect on the change of the day and grab the last remaining balance from the specified date/day.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "7", perhaps you want an `ASC` sort instead of a `DESC` sort.

I would also recommend using table aliases:

```
SELECT m.merchantname as MerchantName,
       COUNT(t.transactionid), 0) as NoofTransaction, 
       COALESCE(SUM(t.transactionamount), 0) as TotalAmount,
       (SELECT s.statementbalance
        FROM statement s
        WHERE t.transactionid = s.transactionid
        ORDER BY statementbalance ASC
        LIMIT 1 
       ) as BalanceRemaining
FROM merchant m LEFT JOIN
     transaction t
     ON m.merchantid = t.merchantid AND t.transactiondate = '2018-01-16'
GROUP BY m.merchantid
ORDER BY m.merchantid ASC;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Do not use them for column aliases.
- I recommend `as` for column aliases.
- `COUNT()` never returns `NULL`, so `COALESCE()` is unnecessary.

Comment: same thing. thing is the data returned is always in reverse irregardless of the order by inside the select query inside the select query